# Example of presenceGroup used in apiRTC.init

Tags: webrtc

In the documentation it is indicated that presenceGroup and subscribeToPresenceGroup can be set in the apiRTCinit.  They are json parameters, but what exactly is the format?  What do they each do, they sound redundant, so I am not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of apiRTC.init() :

```
//apiRTC init
apiRTC.init({
    apiKey : "myDemoApiKey",
    //apiCCId : "229",
    onReady : sessionReadyHandler,
    userData : {
        "lastName": "lastName",
        "firstName": "firstName"
    },
    presenceGroup : ["agent"],
    subscribeToPresenceGroup : ["visitor", "agent"]
});
```

**presenceGroup** : define the groups of the user : user will be considered as present in these groups

**subscribeToPresenceGroup** : define the presence group to which the user has subscribed : user will receive the presence information for these groups.

In our sample : user is connected to group "agent", but will receive presence information for group "visitor" and group "agent"